# Opening Files with Java while Working in Cygwin

Tags: java, file, input, cygwin, filenames

I am running Cygwin on a Windows 7 machine, and using script files to execute Java programs in batch.  My problem is this:  I try to pass in a Cygwin / Linux path to a file, via the command line, and Java converts all of the forward slashes to backslashes.

For instance:

```
java program $scratchname/path_to_folder/ filename_$i.txt
```

Within Java, I take the directory and add the file name to open the file, which usually works with no issues as long as I'm using a Windows command line.  However, in Cygwin Java converts this to:

```
home\scratch\path_to_folder
```

which Cygwin doesn't like.

I don't think this is a simple matter of replacing the backslashes with forward slashes, because Java seems to default to the Windows path conventions when I try to open the file.  I'm guessing this is because Cygwin is pointed to the Windows installation of the JVM.

How can I force Java to use Cygwin / Linux path name conventions on a Windows system?

Answer (score 5):

Java is a Windows program, and as such, only understands Windows paths; launching it from a Cygwin shell can't change that.  You can use `cygpath` to convert paths back and forth.

Reference link: https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using-effectively.html

Example case:

```
  java -jar path/to/your-1.0.jar "$(cygpath -aw /home/YOUR_USER/path/to/file.txt)"
```

Options:

- a provides the absolute path
- w uses the Windows format